# Can anyone identify the hardware/software called "EMC Flex 8-16"?

Tags: storage-area-network, emc

I have discovered a Description entry ("EMC Flex 8-16") in an systems audit which I can't identify. I have asked the Vendors, but have not yet heard back. I'll post an answer myself when I find out.

I have been unable to find info via searching the web (or EMC's support site).

So for myself and others who may in the future attempt to identify the same 
thing, does anyone know what it is?

I have a "gut feeling", but would love to hear from ***anyone who actually knows.***

Many thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 1):

It's a rebadged Brocade Silkworm 200E fibre channel switch.

Answer (score 0):

EMC's Documentum product is built on Adobe Flex. Quite possibly a browser plugin that supports that.